# Web.py installation error

Tags: python, web.py

```
# Python Version

λ python
Python 3.7.0b5 (v3.7.0b5:abb8802389, May 31 2018, 01:54:01) [MSC v.1913 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>




λ pip3 install web.py
Collecting web.py
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/58/21649fc1849b1f688f3d42e25e79615cc573469ea57eaa9e6af70b1e3b87/web.py-0.39.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\KARANJ~2\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-isj4gcc5\web.py\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        from web import __version__
      File "C:\Users\KARANJ~2\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-isj4gcc5\web.py\web\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
        import utils, db, net, wsgi, http, webapi, httpserver, debugerror
      File "C:\Users\Karanjit Singh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\db\__init__.py", line 69
        print "var", var
                  ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("var", var)?

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\KARANJ~2\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-isj4gcc5\web.py\
```

Comment: operating System is Windows 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you're attempting to install a module for Python 3.7, but this module is designed for Python 2.x only. Since in some ways these versions of Python are incompatible, you're getting an error.

In your case, `print "var", var` is Python 2.x-only syntax, it doesn't work in Python 3.x.

So, to solve this, you should install the module for Python 2.x with `pip install web.py`. Another option can be to convert the code of the module to Python 3.x syntax with a tool called *2to3*, however, that may not help if the module uses some C extensions that heavily rely on Python 2.x-only features.

Also, the [official site](http://webpy.org) of web.py says, right on the front page:

> The above version [0.39] only supports Python 2. If you looking for Python 3 support, try the experimental version.
>
> ```
> pip install web.py==0.40-dev1
> ```

I guess, their command is a tiny bit incorrect since one should be using `pip3`, not `pip`. So, if you want Python 3 support, try the experimental version first.

Comment: how can i use 2to3 tool in my case ??

Comment: @thekaranjit, turns out, you don't really need this since there's an experimental version that supports Python3

Comment: Solved :   pip3 install web.py==0.40-dev1  --user